# Java; Jackson; Parsing the array of array json string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I see issues in parsing below json to java object using jackson api.

```
Json String
[
  [
    {
      "id": "6555",
      "fname": "hello",
      "lname": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": "6588",
      "fname": "world",
      "lname": "test"
    }
  ]
]
```

I have created below pojos (removed setters and getters).

```
public class Result {
   List<Student> studentList;
}

public class Student{
   private String id;
   private String fname;
   private String lname;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Result > responseList = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Result>>(){});
```

Jackson has throwing exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token at [Source:
```

Do I need to any specific jackson annotation to `Result` object?

Comment: I would recommend going the other way around, create a list of results and try writing it using your mapper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to Result class, it is redundant. You need to parse it as `List<List<Student>>` because your json structure starts as array and contains another arrays.

Here is how you can parse your :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    List<Result> responseList = mapper.readValue(
            Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json")),
            new TypeReference<List<List<Student>>>() {});

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: thank you.. Yup. I can go with List<List<Student>> and its worked.

Answer (score 1):

If I were trying to write JSON to match the structure you've defined, I'd want:

```
[ 
    { 
        "studentList": 
        [
            {
                "id": "6555",
                "fname": "hello",
                "lname": "test"
            },
            {
                "id": "6588",
                "fname": "world",
                "lname": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Based on the JSON you've laid out, I'd expect Jackson to see that as a `List<List<Student>>`.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. I dont have control and its rest api response.